# Database column defaults not behaving as expected

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an issue where writing a new entry to the database isn't using the configured default values as I'd expect.

I have some classes:

```cs
public class Benefits
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required, ForeignKey("Id"), JsonIgnore]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal BenefitsCost { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(16,8)"), DefaultValue(1)]
    public decimal Modifier { get; set; }

}

public class BenefitsEmployee : Benefits
{}

public class BenefitsDependent : Benefits
{
    [Required]
    public string NameFirst { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NameLast { get; set; }
}
```

In `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
builder.Entity<BenefitsEmployee>().Property(b => b.BenefitsCost).HasDefaultValue(1000);
builder.Entity<BenefitsDependent>().Property(b => b.BenefitsCost).HasDefaultValue(500);
```

And, as last step in `Configure`, roughly:

```cs
var user = new {
    Id = "SomeId",
    NameFirst = "FirstName",
    NameLast = "LastName",
    SalaryBase = 0,
    BenefitsCost = 0,
};

var emp = new Employee
{
    Id = user.Id,
    NameFirst = user.NameFirst,
    NameLast = user.NameLast,
    SalaryBase = user.SalaryBase,
    BenefitsEmployee = new BenefitsEmployee
    {
        BenefitsCost = user.BenefitsCost,
    },
};

await context.AddAsync(emp);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The problem is that `BenefitsCost` is set to `1000` and `Modifier` is set to `0` rather than `0` and `1` as I'd expect.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `0` to `BenefitsCost`, which is the default value for `decimal` type. EF will not even include that column in the generated SQL. That's because from EF's perspective, setting `0` to `BenefitsCost` is equivalent to not setting any value at all, and what it sees is - the user didn't set a value and this column has a default value defined. Therefore, it doesn't bother to include the column in the generated SQL. And for the absent column, the configured default value is supposed to get inserted.

As a solution you can make `BenefitsCost` a nullable type (decimal?). That way, if you set the value `0`, EF will know that you have set a value explicitly. Also, in your configuration, you have to mark the default values as `decimal`, like `1000m`, `500m` etc.

For the `Modifier`, configure the default value in `OnModelCreating` like others. In my experience, setting default value with `[DefaultValue()]` attribute doesn't work. You wouldn't even find the mention of default value in the migration script. May be its a bug, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Regarding `BenefitCost`, is there any way to get around that "feature"? Aside from using `0` as the default?

Comment: @Ouroborus I provided the info solely based on my observation of the generated SQL. There still might be some work-around, or even valid configuration that I'm not aware of. You can use `0.1` in place of `0`. I'll try to update the answer and notify you if I can find any helpful information.

Comment: @Ouroborus I updated the post to add a solution. In short, change `BenefitsCost` to `decimal?` type.

Comment: I think I stumbled across that accidentally and didn't realize it. I'm now using `decimal?` and setting the intended defaults in the constructors, while using object initializers and conditional assignments to update values as needed.